# The format of the URI could not be determined - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having following code which runs perfectly on dev server but gives error on live server.

It gives me following error

System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

```
<-----------------Code Started--------------------->

private void InsertThrAPI(clsProductProp objProductProp)
{
    xmldata data = new xmldata();
    data.Items = new xmldataProducts[1];
    data.Items[0] = new xmldataProducts();


    objProduct.stockstatus = Convert.ToString(objProductProp.stockstatus);
    objProduct.price = Convert.ToString(objProductProp.price);
    objProduct.productname = Convert.ToString(objProductProp.productname);
    objProduct.productshortname = Convert.ToString(objProductProp.productshortname);
    objProduct.productcode = Convert.ToString(objProductProp.productcode);
    objProduct.description = Convert.ToString(objProductProp.description);
    objProduct.technicalspecs = Convert.ToString(objProductProp.technicalspecs);
    objProduct.shippingcost = Convert.ToString(objProductProp.shippingcost);
    objProduct.productweight = Convert.ToString(objProductProp.productweight);
    objProduct.vendorprice = Convert.ToString(objProductProp.vendorprice);
    if (objProductProp.shipping == true || objProductProp.shipping == Convert.ToBoolean(1))
    {
        objProduct.shipping = "Y";
    }
    else
    {
        objProduct.shipping = "N";
    }

    //Populate the product fields here

    data.Items[0].StockStatus = objProduct.stockstatus;
    data.Items[0].ProductPrice = objProduct.price;
    data.Items[0].ProductName = objProduct.productname;
    data.Items[0].ProductNameShort = objProduct.productshortname;
    data.Items[0].ProductCode = objProduct.productcode;
    data.Items[0].ProductDescription = objProduct.description;
    data.Items[0].TechSpecs = objProduct.technicalspecs;
    data.Items[0].FreeShippingItem = objProduct.shipping;
    data.Items[0].Fixed_ShippingCost = objProduct.shippingcost;
    data.Items[0].ProductWeight = objProduct.productweight;
    data.Items[0].Vendor_Price = objProduct.vendorprice;




    string productXML = Utils.GetProductXML(data);
    string APIURL = Utils.GetAPIPostURL(ImportMode.Insert);
    XMLPostManager manager = new XMLPostManager();
    string response = manager.SendXMLToURL(APIURL, productXML);

    //Response.Write(response);
}
```

Comment: What is the input that causes your code to fail?

Comment: well how about telling what line produces the error, what the value of the URL is on both dev and prod.

Comment: Well the only thing in the code that is obviously an URL is the variable `APIURL` Set a breakpoint at that line run the code and look at what it contains for starters. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see the URL to tell you what's wrong with it, but you can check to make sure that the URL is valid like this:

```
if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(APIURL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
{
    //url is valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

I guess you main problem is that this only happens in live and not in your dev system, so debugging is hard?

A couple of suggestion:

- Look in to adding logging code - there's a lot of info out there, but
  something like [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) would be a good start. Add logging code
  to this method and you should hopefully see the data that is causing
  issues.
- See if you can add more realistic data to your unit tests or
  other internal tests and see if you can spot this.